# Why doesn't window.devicePixelRatio change on zoom in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, devicepixelratio

Context: I'm using `window.devicePixelRatio` to determine the display resolution for a few canvases on a website.

To the best of my knowledge, the DPR value should change when zooming in and out on a website. This is what happens on Chrome. But it doesn't seem to happen in Safari. Querying the value of `window.devicePixelRatio` or `devicePixelRatio` from the JS Console always returns the same value, no matter how much I zoom in or out. I've tried this on three separate computers, all of them Macs running either Safari v13.1.2, v14.1.2, or v15.1.

The [MDN Web Docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) on `Window.devicePixelRatio` implies that the DPR *should* change on zoom, both in its definition at the top and in its example code. The [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/Overview.bs) linked by MDN says the following (bolded emphasis mine):

> The *devicePixelRatio* attribute must return the result of the following *determine the device pixel ratio* algorithm: If there is no output device, return 1 and abort these steps. Let *CSS pixel size* be the size of a CSS pixel at the **current page zoom scale factor** and at a pinch zoom scale factor of 1.0. Let *device pixel size* be the vertical size of a device pixel of the output device. Return the result of dividing *CSS pixel size* by *device pixel size*.

Should Safari's `window.devicePixelRatio` be changing on zoom? If the DPR doesn't change with zooming, is there a different way to determine a good canvas display resolution on Safari?

This is my first question on StackOverflow so please let me know if anything can be improved.

Comment: "Should Safari's window.devicePixelRatio be changing on zoom?" Yes it should. "is there a different way to determine a good canvas display resolution" yes, the ResizeObserver's `devicePixelContentBoxSize` is better. "on Safari" nope... (`window.innerWidth/window.outerWidth` could probably be used for a poor workaround but I don't know of a good way to determine if this workaround is necessary or not)